# What files shall I put into rep to keep dependencies and modules settings tracked?

Tags: intellij-idea

Please tell me what files shall I put into git rep watch in order to keep already configured dependencies and modules settings tracked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the [Knowledge Base document](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067).